# How to load private git repository as package at azure website?

Tags: node.js, git, express, npm, azure-web-app-service

I've an express web app where I have a lot of stuff and want to split it into modules.

One of the way is that move shared code to private git repository and use it as a package. Npm support such using. But I didn't find that azure website does.
If anyone knows how to load private git repository as package at azure website?

Or may be another way to share code in between apps in secure, private way at azure website?

Answer (score 1):

If your private repo is on Github, you can use [Personal Access Tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

1. Create a token for your service, let's say 'azure-website' at https://github.com/settings/tokens/new. Make sure to copy or memorize the token.
2. Add the repo to your project dependencies via `npm install --save` like this:

   `npm install --save 'https://your_token@github.com/user/private-repo.git'`

   where `your_token` is your private token.

Comment: Tried, but it shows me 404 on `npm install --save 'https://your_token@github.com/user/private-repo.git'`.                        While `git clone 'https://your_token@github.com/user/private-repo.git'` is works fine.